# How to print JTextField into a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield

Ok so I've been trying to work on this but I'm completely stuck, I'm sure it's pretty simple.

So I have a set of JTextField that I want to print on a JTable. How would I go about that?
This is part of my JTable code:

```
static String[] vdLabel = {"Date", "Trans. Type", "Check No.", "Trans Description",      "Payment/Debit(-)", "Deposit/Credit(+)", "Balance"};
static DefaultTableModel viewTable = new DefaultTableModel(vdLabel,0);
static JTable viewLabel = new JTable(viewTable);
```

I want to place these variables under the "Date" "Trans Type" etc.

```
static JTextField dateTrans = new JTextField();
static JTextField typeOfTrans = new JTextField();
static JTextField checkNo = new JTextField();
```

If you don't understand what I'm trying to do here's a little picture that may help.

http://www.javalobby.org/articles/jtable/images/img2.png

In that picture there's "Title" "Artist" and "Album" that's my string variable 'vdLabel'

How can I add A string for the date, etc. to vdLabel and then add that to the JTable?

Comment: First off, if the columns are strings, then you can double click on them and edit them by default. Could you explain what you want your end result to look like? It sounds like you could just add a row to the JTable and it would be what you want.

Comment: Let the table and model take care of it.  Returing `Date` from the `getColumnClass` method for the appropriate column will allow the table to use it's inbuilt renderers and editors. If you prefer, you can establish your own. Take a look at [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

Comment: Ok so basically my program is a banking program through GUI.. One card is holding the JTextField and the user enters the string or float from that card window. Once that user enters the string into the JTextField, I want to grab that specific one and put it in the JTable. But the user shouldn't be able to simply just type into the JTable.

Comment: I'm looking over it right now, if it works like you say it'll go to the appropriate column then I think I might understand.. I'll go and try to get it working now.

Comment: Tip:  Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever) to ensure they are notified of new comments.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make some of your table cells editable, you don't quite do this.  Instead of using the `DefaultTableModel`, you use your own subclass of `AbstractTableModel`, and you override `isCellEditable` appropriately.  You also override `getValueAt` appropriately, returning `java.util.Date`s for dates. Swing will use the appropriate renderers and editors based on the value.

Look at the [Java Tutorial on How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) before you do anything else.  In any case, make sure you have a model. Then, if you are dynamically adding rows to the table, you'd want to have a button at the end of each row.  Selecting it should trigger an action that causes the controller to add a record to the model.  The controller should then send a `TableModelChanged` event. The `JTable` should have been registered with the controller, so it gets the event, and redraws itself.

Comment: I don't want the cells editable but I want to be able to get variables from another card. For example a button opens a window to enter the information. The user enters this information like, "Name", etc. I want to be able to grab that name variable and put it in the JTable on a different card window. So that JTable isn't editable

Comment: Use models and events then.  Do not try to add the JTextField to the JTable. When the user changes the JTextField, it sends an ActionEvent to its registered ActionListeners.  Its Document also sends a DocumentEvent too its listeners. Write an ActionListener that updates your program's model.  Write a TableModelChanged event that your JTable listens to.  Don't try to do everything in the Swing classes.

Answer (score 2):

> For example a button opens a window to enter the information. The user enters this information like, "Name", etc. I want to be able to grab that name variable and put it in the JTable on a different card window

When the user clicks the "Save" button on this `modal JDialog` you can just get the data from the text fields and then add a row to the `DefaultTableModel` using the `addRow(....)` method.